# Android otp related

Tags: android

I have a XML file with 5 edittext field of input type as number with max size as 1. In my activity I use addtextchangelistner on edittext.ontextchange method I checked if length of edittext is 1 then requeatfocus to next field and so on. I use setTransformationmethod to get password field. It works fine in first time but when I enter the field for second time it shows password digit

Comment: Please add your relevent code so we can check it.

Comment: This is how my activity looks like

Comment: And how are we supposed to help you without seeing any code?